# How do I search for an address and display address JSON data onto my page with ReactJS? I am only able to get it to console log in the .then

Tags: reactjs, forms, axios

I am able to get the data to log to the console in the .then but everything I have tried is unsuccessful in being able to search a specific address and then display the JSON data onto the page.

```js
axios
      .post('https://dtapiuat.datatree.com/api/Report/GetReport', body)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data);

        self.setState({ Report: res.Report, loading: false });
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  render() {
    // if (!this.state.Report.Reports) {
    //   return <span>Loading...</span>;
    // }

    return (
      <Fragment>
        <Container>
          <div id='main'>
            <h1>Get Reports</h1>
            <input
              name='text'
              type='text'
              placeholder='Search'
              onChange={(event) => this.handleOnChange(event)}
              value={this.state.searchValue}
            />
            <button onClick={this.handleSearch}>Search</button>

            {this.state.Reports ? (
              <div id='Report-container'>
                {this.state.Report.map((Report, index) => (
                  <div class='single-Report' key={index}>
                    <h2>{this.state.Report}</h2>
                  </div>
                ))}
              </div>
            ) : (
              <p>Try Searching For a Report</p>
            )}
          </div>
        </Container>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `res.Report` to `res.data.Report`.Also, make sure that self is indeed referring to the correct `this`. If this doesn't resolve the issue then post the log of your console.log.

Comment: I tried that and the output was the same. Right now I am able to log the json data to the console from the url. Everytime I click on the button it just logs the json data.